# Using Select-String to Match Multiple Single-Line Patterns and Write to Output

Tags: regex, powershell, select-string

I am trying to build a simple script to utilize regex and match multiple patterns on a single line - recursively throughout an input file, and write the result to an output file. But I'm hitting a wall:

**Sample text:**

```
BMC12345 COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  31 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT111D.DIH0345S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED DUE TBMC123456 COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  10 PHYSICAL (10 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
```

Here's what I've got so far:

```
$table = [regex] "'.*'"
$discard = [regex] "\d* PHYSICAL"

Select-String -Pattern ($table, $discard) -AllMatches .\test.txt | foreach {
    $_.Matches.Value
} > output.txt
```

**Output:**

```
'KDDT111D.DIH0345S'
```

**Desired output:**

```
'KDDT111D.DIH0345S' 10 Physical
```

For some reason I am unable to get both patterns to write to output.txt.
Ideally once I get this working I would like to use `Export-Csv` to get something a bit cleaner like:

```
|KDDT111D|DIH0345S|10 Physical|
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you will find the `-match` operator a bit more suited to this. [*grin*] using named matches against your sample stored in `$InStuff`, this ...

```
$InStuff -match ".+SPACE '(?<Space>.+)\.(?<SubSpace>.+)'.+: (?<Discarded>.+) \(.+"
```

... gives the following set of matches ...

```
Name                           Value                                                                              
----                           -----                                                                              
Space                          KDDT111D                                                                           
SubSpace                       DIH0345S                                                                           
Discarded                      10 PHYSICAL                                                                        
0                              BMC12345 COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS: 31 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT111D.DIH0345...
```

the named matches can be addressed by `$Matches.<the capture group name>`.

Comment: I don't believe this is the direction I want to go, but I appreciate the idea. The input file will have hundreds of records similar to the sample text I provided above. I would like to have the script pick up the input file from a specified directory. The script should then recursively extract the 'Space', 'SubSpace' and 'Discarded' match values, and write that output for each record to a txt/csv file.

Comment: @Jonmonjovi - ok ... but regex is _usually_ the way to go for large files. [*grin*] i cannot get the Select-String cmdlet to work with an array of patterns such as you listed. i suspect it will not work at all that way. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Unfortunately I have been unable to replicate your results using the match operator and my input file. PS version info below:                                      
`PSVersion                      5.1.17134.407
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.17134.407
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1`

Comment: there are so many ways a regex can go wrong [*grin*] ... it's nearly meaningless to discuss it without seeing both the actual code you used AND a few lines of the actual [sanitized] data file.

Answer (score 1):

You have run into a **`Select-String` limitation**: The `.Matches` property of the [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) objects that `Select-String` emits for each input object (line) only ever contains the (potentially multiple) matches for the *first* regex passed to the 
`-Pattern` parameter.<sup>[1]</sup>

You can **work around the problem** by passing a *single* regex instead, by combining the input regexes via *alternation* (`|`):

```
Select-String -Pattern ($table, $discard -join '|') -AllMatches .\test.txt | 
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } > output.txt
```

A simplified example:

```
# ('f.', '.z' -join '|') -> 'f.|.z'
'foo bar baz' | Select-String -AllMatches ('f.', '.z' -join '|') |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value }
```

The above yields:

```
fo
az
```

proving that the matches for *both* regexes were reported.

**Caveat** re **output ordering**: Using alternation (`|`) causes the matches for a given input string to be reported in the order in which they're found *in the input*, not in the order in which the *regexes were specified*.
That is, both `-Pattern 'f.|.z'` and `-Pattern '.z|f.'` above would have resulted in the same output order.

---

<sup>[1] The problem exists as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0-preview.4  and is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7765)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the contributors for the ideas and learning experience. I was able to get the desired output utilizing a combination of both answers receive.

I found that the `-match` operator only returned the first occurrence of the regex pattern match from the source file, so I needed to add a `foreach` loop in order to recursively return matches throughout the log file.

I also modified the regex to include only discard values greater than 0.

**Sample Text:**

```
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDAICH0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED DUE TOBMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 PHYSICAL (0 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  3499604 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDAIND0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED BMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 PHYSICAL (0 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  1 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDCISR0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED DUE TOBMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 PHYSICAL (0 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  9185775 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDIADR0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED BMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  11 PHYSICAL (11 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDICHT0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED DUE TOBMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 PHYSICAL (0 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  2387375 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDICMS0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED BMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 PHYSICAL (0 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  1632821 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDIPRV0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED BMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 PHYSICAL (0 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
BMC51472I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  0 ROWS SELECTED FOR SPACE 'KDDT000D.KDLADD0S', 0 ROWS SELECTED BUT DISCARDED DUE TOBMC51479I COMBINED PHASE STATISTICS:  24845 PHYSICAL (24845 LOGICAL) RECORDS DISCARDED TO SYSDISC
```

**Example:**

```
  $regex = ".+SPACE '(?<Space>.+)\.(?<SubSpace>.+)'.+: (?<Discarded>.+) .[1-9][0-9]*\s\b"

    $timestamp = Get-Date
    $timestamp = Get-Date $timestamp -f "MM_dd_yy"
    $dir = "C:\Users\JonMonJovi\"

    cat $dir\*.log.txt | where {
        $_ -match $regex
    } | foreach {
        $Matches.Space, $Matches.SubSpace, $Matches.Discarded -join "|"
    } > C:\Users\JonMonJovi\Discarded\Discard_Log_$timestamp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
KDDT000D|KDIADR0S| 11 PHYSICAL
KDDT000D|KDLADD0S| 24845 PHYSICAL
```

From here I am able to use the pipe delimited .txt output file to import into Excel, fulfilling my requirements.